# Feature Testing with Filepicker.io and Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, filepicker.io, poltergeist

I am currently working on feature testing a Filepicker.io upload form and cannot get a the file upload to work. I am using the [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) driver for Capybara and from the debugging I have been able to do, the Filepicker iframe is never loading. I have confirmed this by using the remote debugging of Poltergeist.

Here is a sample of the test code:

```rb
within_fieldset 'Photos' do
  click_button 'Find Photo'
end
within_frame 'filepicker_dialog' do
  attach_file '#fileUploadInput', Rails.root.join('spec', 'files', 'photo.jpg')
end
```

And the error being produced:

```
Failure/Error: within_frame '#filepicker_dialog' do
 Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
   Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"push_frame","args":["#filepicker_dialog"]}. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker.
```

Attempting to manually trigger Filepicker through the javascript console also yields no results.

Comment: I was able to follow this guide, http://mscottford.com/post/30910962407/getting-spooky-remote-debugging-with-poltergeist-on, and get remote debugging working with Poltergeist. Upon further inspection of the page I can see that the Filepicker interface and iframe is not opening, however no console errors are being given.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to increase the timeout ?

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:timeout => 50})
end
```

as the default timeout is 30

Answer (score 0):

The Capybara API for `within_frame` is a bit weird. It expects a frame *name*, not a CSS selector for the frame. So Poltergeist is looking for a frame named "#filepicker_dialog" - I suspect this is your problem.

Comment: Noticed this and updated the code, but I have now determined the real issue to be that the frame is never loading or being added to the DOM.